# Replacing R loops with creative uses of ddply or ply-family functions

Tags: r, postgresql, plyr

I am an advanced beginner in **R** who would deeply appreciate your thoughts about the following problem. Bits and pieces of this problem might be solved by using the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package, or by other `ply`-family functions. A full solution still eludes me, though.

**DESIRED ADVICE**: Faster **R**- or Postgre SQL-based solution to the following problem that could be implemented on a Mac. Server-side solutions should be avoided. Timing the code excerpted below suggests that the bottlenecks are a sampling of a large dataframe and an `rbind` step --- that are then in a `for` loop.

**TASK**: Find the de-identified medical patients who stop taking a particular medication for too long (*i.e.*, those who have even one medication 'gaps' longer than some statistically derived threshold). R dataframe `Claims` has rows that represent separate prescriptions. De-identified patient codes are stored in `Claims$id`, prescription start dates in `Claims$sdate`, and prescription end dates in `Claims$edate`.

The following shows two examples from an **R** dataframe `Claims`. Dates are written here as integers representing days since January 1st, 2000:

```
  id    sdate    edate
  A     1        90
  A     14       15
  A     121      180
  B     1        30
  B     2000     2030
  ...   ...      ...
```

Statistical analysis of all gaps show that the threshold gap length is 60 days.

- **A correct procedure would move only Patient A to the next steps of the analysis.** This is because Patient A effectively has only two prescriptions separated by only a 30-day gap (from Day 91 to 120, after ending his overlapping first/second prescriptions and starting his third prescription). Patient B, meanwhile, has a 1970-day gap.
- **But the wrong procedure would eliminate Patient A.** For instance, pairwise comparison of his second and third prescriptions would identify a false too-long gap (of length 75 days, from Days 15 to 91).

**[EDIT] NEWEST APPROACH:** This approach uses the **R** functions `IRanges::IRanges()` and `base::split` to process 3 million records for 600,000 patients in 0.3 seconds.

```
ClaimsByMember <- with(Claims, split(IRanges(as.numeric(Claims$startdate), as.numeric(Claims$enddate)), member_id))
Gaps <- as.data.frame((width(gaps(ClaimsByMember))))
Gaps <- select(Gaps, -group)
Gaps <- as.data.frame(Gaps)
colnames(Gaps) <- c("member_id", "daysgap")
```

**OLDER APPROACH:** This method based on the **R** packages `IRanges` and `dplyr` can process ~20,000 rows for ~4,000 patients in ~7 seconds (~3,000 rows per second) when executed by the most recent version of R on a Mac Book Pro with 16 GB of RAM. But it slows to somewhere around 0.5 to 8 h for 3 million rows and 600,000 patients (100 to 1,600 rows per second; uncertainty in runtime exists because I did not time the procedure using `system.time`).

```
  library(IRanges)
  library(plyr)

  # Read in the raw dataset.
    Claims <- read.csv("claims.csv")

  > id    sdate    edate
  > A     1        90
  > A     14       15
  > A     121      180
  > B     1        30
  > B     2000     2030
  > ...   ...      ... 

  smart <- function(Claims)
  {
    # MemberClaims_I is an IRanges object that handles each sdate/edate 
    # row of prescription data in MemberClaims as a sequence of 
    # consecutive integers with some length ('width').
    # Each of these sequences is defined by the variables start and end.
    # width is automatically calculated
      MemberClaims_I <- IRanges(start = as.numeric(Claims$startdate), 
        end = as.numeric(Claims$enddate))

    # MemberClaims_Red is an IRanges object that stores the fully      
    # overlapped ('reduced') prescriptions of the current patient
    # as sequences of consecutive integers
      MemberClaims_Red <- reduce(MemberClaims_I)

    # MemberGaps is an IRanges object that stores the gaps      
    # between reduced prescription as sequences of consecutive integers
      MemberGaps <- as.data.frame(gaps(MemberClaims_Red))

  }

  member_id <- levels(Claims$member_id)
  Gaps <- ddply(Claims, .(member_id), smart)


  # Create a dataframe listing all patients.
  # Patients must be constructed before moving to the next steps of this analysis
  # Claims$id refers to patient ids
    Patients <- as.data.frame(levels(Claims$id))
    Patients

  > id    
  > A     
  > A     
  > A     
  > B     
  > B     
  > ...
```

`Gaps` at this point can be subjected to analyses that define the threshold gap length to exclude patients with too-long gaps. Ultimately, rows are added to `Patients` in order to calculate the therapy time for this medication.

Thoughts on how to use `ply`-family functions to accelerate this protocol?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you want speed, stop using `plyr` and start using `dplyr` or `data.table`. Data table will be fastest, `dplyr` will be similar to `plyr` but much faster.

Comment: How would the `data.table` package be used? Would it basically entail looping through my `Claims` dataset (as a `data.table`)?

Comment: Would it entail merely converting my `Claims` dataframe into a datable? Or is something deeper involved? From my understanding, this package is very good at calculating sums and means over the `by` variable, but I would love to learn how it would perform the work of the custom function `smart` that I defined above.

Answer (score 1):

Treating periods of prescriptions as sequence of ranges we can use mathematical operations of sets to summarise them for each patient. I've made some time ago (for completely another task) some functions working with sets described as a sequence of range indexes.

```
# this function tidies the definition of the set 
# making union of stacked and overlapping ranges
#
# dirty_bri  <- matrix(c(1,10,8,13,23,32,32,35,45,48,50,77,55,70,88,88), nrow = 2)
#
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    8   23   32   45   50   88
# [2,]   10   13   32   35   48   77   88

tidy_bri <- function(bri) {
  false_ends <- sapply(bri[2,], function(x) any(x >= bri[1,]-1 & x < bri[2,]) )
  false_starts <- sapply(bri[1,], function(x) any(x > bri[1,] & x <= bri[2,]+1) )
  matrix(sort(c(bri[1,][!false_starts], bri[2,][!false_ends])), nrow = 2)
}

# tidy_bri(dirty_bri) -> my_bri
#
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1   23   45   50   88
# [2,]   13   35   48   77   88

# calculates middle gaps in bri
midgaps_bri <- function(bri) {
  bri[1,] <- bri[1,] - 1
  bri[2,] <- bri[2,] + 1
  matrix(bri[-c(1, length(bri))], nrow =2)
}

# midgaps_bri(my_bri)
#
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   14   36   49   78
# [2,]   22   44   49   87
```

Now we can make usage of this functions and work with your data.

```
require("dplyr")

df <- read.table(text = "id    sdate    edate
  A     1        90
  A     14       15
  A     121      180
  B     1        30
  B     2000     2030", header = T)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(bri = list(tidy_bri(matrix(c(sdate, edate), nrow = 2, byrow = T)))) -> df1

df1$gaps <- lapply(df1$bri, midgaps_bri) %>% lapply(function(mm) mm[2,] - mm[1,] + 1)
df1$maxgap <- unlist(lapply(df1$gaps, max))

df1 %>% View

    id  bri                     gaps    maxgap
1   A   c(1, 90, 121, 180)      30      30
2   B   c(1, 30, 2000, 2030)    1969    1969
```

Now you can filter this `data.frame` with necessary threshold value. Probably columns `bri` and `gaps` are not necessary here.

```
df1 %>% select(-bri, -gaps) %>% filter(maxgap >= 60)

#       id maxgap
#   (fctr)  (dbl)
# 1      B   1969
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick update. I've found that the following **R** script accomplishes the task very quickly: 3 million rows for 600,000 patients in 0.35 seconds total.

```
  ClaimsByMember <- with(Claims, split(IRanges(as.numeric(Claims$startdate), as.numeric(Claims$enddate)), member_id))
  Gaps <- as.data.frame((width(gaps(ClaimsByMember))))
  Gaps <- select(Gaps, -group)
  Gaps <- as.data.frame(Gaps)
  colnames(Gaps) <- c("member_id", "daysgap")
```